# Precise definition of a limit to negative infinity

Tags: limits

$ lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac {\sin (x)}{1+x} = 0$

So far I've got:

For any $ \epsilon > 0 $, there exists $N$ such that if $x < N$, then $|\frac {\sin (x)}{1+x} - 0| < \epsilon$

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: hint: Sine is bounded, $1+x$ isn't.

Comment: what is the question exactly? also, isn't that supposed to be $-\infty$?

Comment: @Giovanni, yes, my bad

Comment: what is $N$? the notation "$N$" is commonly used for positive integers, since you are using as a negative number you might want to state it clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$; then 
$$
\left|\frac{\sin x}{1+x}\right| \leq \frac{1}{1+x} < \frac{1}{x} < \varepsilon
$$
if $x > 1/\varepsilon$.

Comment: ... just minor technicality: your $x$ tends to $\infty$ instead of $-\infty$.

Comment: @user251257: Thanks; I answered one of the previous versions of the question; but, yes, the result is unchanged.